# MQTT - Is there a way to check if the client is still connected

Tags: python, mqtt

Is there a way to check if the client is still connected to the MQTT broker?

Something like

```
if client.isConnected(): # for example
    # if True then do stuff
```

Edit: There was instance where my Raspberry Pi stopped receiving from the client although it was still (from the look of it, the code was still showing updated results) running.

Here is the code since I may be doing something wrong:

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(address, 1883, 60)

while True:
    data = getdata()
    client.publish("$ahmed/",data,0)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

The thing is that I was away, so I am not even sure why it stopped! Only if I restart my broker then it will start receiving again.

Comment: Look here : https://github.com/TNChalise/php-mqtt. The code is written for php client.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can activate a flag in on_connect and deactivate it in on_disconnect. In this way you can know if the client is connected or not.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

flag_connected = 0

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   global flag_connected
   flag_connected = 1

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
   global flag_connected
   flag_connected = 0

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.connect(server,port)
client.loop_forever()
if flag_connected == 1:
   # Publish message
else:
   # Wait to reconnect
```

Comment: btw the `loop_forever()` is a blocking call. we never reach `if flag_connected == 1:` line. calling `loop()` would work ?

Comment: `loop_start()` is an option that starts a thread which calls `loop_forever()` or you can do a while loop that calls `loop()`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see one in the [doc](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/) but there are the `on_disconnect` `on_connect` callbacks that can be used to set your own state variable

EDIT:

You need to call one of the [`loop`](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/#network-loop) functions to give the client cycles to handle the network operations:

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(address, 1883, 60)

while True:
    data = getdata()
    client.publish("$ahmed/",data,0)
    client.loop(timeout=1.0, max_packets=1)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: I have included more details to my question and the reason behind it.

Comment: Edited answer to fit the actual problem

Comment: It worked for around two hours but then I had to restart the client's code because the broker stopped receiving again. At least I don't need to restart the Raspberry Pi now, but why did the client stop if it still showing the updated results? I print `sent` right after the publish line.

Comment: Because calling publish doesn't actually send the message, it queues it for the loop function to handle. Try increasing the max_packets count of it's still having problems

Comment: How much do you recommend so it doesn't reduce the performance?

Comment: I just read the docs again. Since the loop is supposedly running forever, wouldn't be recommended to use `loop_forever()` function?

Comment: loop_forever will not return, so you will need to run it on a separate thread

Comment: How about the number of the `max_packets`?

Comment: I tried to set to 5 & 1000, the 5 loop lasted a lot longer before it stopped. How should I stop it from stopping?

Comment: max_packets isn't used any more, please just don't set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `will` message to do this.

```
client=mqtt.Client()
client.will_set('will_message_topic',payload=time.time(),qos=2,retain=True)
client.connect(address,1883,60)
client.publish('will_message_topic',payload='I am alive',qos=2,retain=True)
client.loop_start()#this line is important
while 1:#faster than while True
    you loop
```

By leaving a `will` message, you can use another client to make sure if the client is online or not.

Comment: while 1: and while True: 1 are the same for Python 3. But I just googled it and in python 2 the difference is substantial.

Comment: Oh, I think I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also view this article: [How to use MQTT in Python (Paho)](https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-python)
A block of code from the article answering your question:

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client


broker = 'broker.io'
port = 8888
client_id = 'client_id '
username = 'username'
password = 'password'


def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)
    # Set Connecting Client ID
    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the paho mqtt client has a is_connected() method that can be used.
this method is in the paho client.py file

here is an example

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

this.mClientName = "MQ_Client_" + "your unique client name"
this.mClientMq = mqtt.Client(this.mClientName)
retVal = this.mClientMq.connect(this.mBrokerIp, this.mBrokerPort)

def getMqClientStatus():
    val = this.mClientMq.is_connected() # returns True or False
    valStr = "Connected"
    if val == 0:
        valStr = "Not Connected"
    return val, valStr
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the API available.
You just use client.is_connected() returns True or False.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).