# The appropriate value of max_packets for MQTT loop function

Tags: python, mqtt

I have this code that should run indefinitely, however, it doesn't. It keeps on stopping every few hours from the client's side (stop publishing, the loop keeps on running, but nothing is received at the broker), and the only thing that can be done is to rerun it again.

I was advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093078/mqtt-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-client-is-still-connected/36093631?noredirect=1) to increase the number of max_packets for the loop function, but it's not working and the client stops publishing randomly without continuing. What should be done? I tried the values of 1, 3, 5, 50 and a 1000 but no use.

Code:

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(address, 1883, 60)

while True:
    data = getdata()
    client.publish("$ahmed/",data,0)
    client.loop(timeout=1.0, max_packets = 1) # what should be the parameters here so it doesn't stop publishing?
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned the subscriber at all, how do you know nothing is arriving at the broker?

Comment: @hardillb oh my bad, but my code that is running at the broker makes sure that whenever a message is received then it is to be printed out.

Comment: The max_packets parameter isn't used any more, please just don't set it.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should either use loop_forever() or loop_start(), loop() on its own allows more control but is usually unnecessary. In your case, use loop_start() only as @Kiran has suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to applications messages which are published/subscribed, MQTT also have internal keepalive to avoid problem of half open TCP connections([1](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-10-alive-client-take-over)). And it is the responsibility of client to make sure keepalives are sent. As per specification, the broker will disconnect clients which doesn't send keepalives in one and half times of keepalive time interval( in absence of other messages).

In addition to sending messages, the `loop()*` functions also maintains this keepalive traffic flow between broker and client.

A random try: Try using `loop_start()` once instead of calling `loop()` in while loop. E.g.

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(address)
#runs a thread in background to call loop function internally. 
#In addition, this also reconnects to broker on a lost connection. 
client.loop_start()

while True:
    data = getdata()
    client.publish("$ahmed",data)
client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: I have included this in my code for testing. I will choose it as the correct answer if it works out.

Answer (score 1):

Just a random guess... has the client disconnected?

In your code you are not handling [any callback](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt#callbacks) like `on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc)` which is *called when the client disconnects from the broker.*

```
def on_disconnect_handler(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        print("Unexpected disconnection.")

client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect_handler
```

You are also not checking `loop()` [return value](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L760):
*Returns MQTT_ERR_SUCCESS on success.

        Returns >0 on error.*

You should do something like

```
while True:
    rc = client.loop(timeout=1.0)
    if rc:
        # handle loop error here
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make the client connect every time the loops is through. I have tested it and connecting to the brokers doesn't any significant extra latency on the flow. Since I have to rerun the program to make work it again, I may as well reconnect the client in the loop, so I don't have to do it myself. This is the rawest idea I could come up with that seems to be working without any problems.

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(address, 1883, 60)

while True:
    client.connect(address, 1883, 60) # just let it reconnect every time it loops ;)! 
    data = getdata()
    client.publish("$ahmed/",data,0)
    client.loop(timeout=1.0, max_packets = 1) 
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: If your going to do that use the `single` function which does a connect, publish, disconnect all in one go https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/#global-helper-functions

Comment: Please do not do this.

Comment: @ralight wouldn't it be kind of you to explain too?!

Comment: It's just entirely unnecessary to reconnect 5 times every second. As @hardillb says you could use publish.single() instead, but if you are publishing at this rate the better solution is to have a constantly connected client.