# python paho client broker connection

Tags: python, mqtt, iot, mosquitto, paho

My publisher and broker are working on different systems. I am using QOS=2 for delivery of messages.I am using python paho mqtt broker. It is further extension to 
[MQTT - Is there a way to check if the client is still connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093078/mqtt-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-client-is-still-connected)

1) When I publish a message to connected broker, it acknowledge me by calling on_publish() callback. but when I disconnected my broker running on different machine from the network, the publisher stores the publish message on local machine and again when I connect my broker to network it publishes all previous messages to broker. I think these messages stored as inflight messages (not confirmed), if these messages are inflight messages, then  where these messages are stored,is there any limit of these inflight messages as I have not include anything in my code regarding inflight messages.

2)In first case I disconnect my broker from the network, now I shutdown my broker and again connect to network,  my program call on_disconnect() callback says unexpected disconnection, then publishes all unpublished messages to broker.
    a) I am confused why on_disconnect() callback calls only when I shut down by broker not on when I disconnect my broker from my local network.
   b) on_disconnect() method calls only when my broker again connect to network.
      Is there any way if my broker disconnect suddenly, then immediately it will be informed to publisher?

3) I am using mqtt in real time gps tracking, I want to store messages to local db when publisher not connected to broker , but I can't find any way how publisher comes to know immediately when it disconnected from broker.

4) Is using QOS=2 is best way to ensure message delivery to broker or using local db for storage purpose when disconnected to broker and then sync automatically with local db to publish all messages