# Python paho-mqtt delayed connection status

Tags: python, mqtt

This code snippet:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect('localhost')
print(client.is_connected())

while not client.is_connected():
  client.loop()
  print(client.is_connected())

print(client.is_connected())
client.disconnect()
```

produces:

```
False
False
True
True
```

which indicates that upon return from `connect()` the connection status is not yet updated. The documentation (https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#connect-reconnect-disconnect) reads *The connect() function connects the client to a broker. This is a blocking function.* This suggests that the status should be accurate on return from `connect()`. Am I missing something? Is there another way to test if `client` is connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting to a broker is a two stage process:

- Establish a connection (TCP/TLS/Websocket etc)
- Perform the MQTT connection handshake (`CONNECT`/`CONNACK`)

Taking a look at [the source](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/71e29222421b83774af8c241898d4f1f15f58b8d/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L911) it appears that when you call `client.connect('localhost')` the first step (establish network connection) is completed before the function returns but the second is not (the [`CONNECT`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Ref363033523) packet is sent but the function does not wait for the [`CONNACK`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Ref362964779)).

The connection status (as reported by `client.is_connected()`) is only updated when the `CONNACK` packet has been processed (and this is done in the `loop`).

The documentation does not cover this as well as it could (and a few issues have been raised, e.g. [this](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/4) and [this](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/454) edit - I created a [PR](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/pull/615) to update the docs).

> Is there another way to test if client is connected?

A better approach is to use the `on_connect` callback (as shown in the [examples](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/client_sub.py)). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44845759/11810946) provides further info.

Comment: Good info, thank you. The source code clearly confirms the problem raised in https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/4. I don't understand why it was closed without correcting the documentation: `connect()` is not a blocking call.

Comment: Additionally, an example with `on_connect()` callback has the same defect. Callback is not called until the loop is run a few times.

Comment: "connect() is not a blocking call" - well to be fair it does block; just not for as long as may be expected. "`on_connect()` callback has the same defect" - this is to be expected because it is only called when the connection is fully established (i.e. `CONNACK` has been received) and `CONNACK` is processed in `loop`.